# Exercise on Periodicity of a Markov chain.

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A Markov chain on states $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ has the transition probability matrix

$$P=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
How can I determine the period of each states of the Markov chain ?

I noticed that it is an irreducible Markov chain. So every state will have the same period. Is there any easy technique to find the period of the given Markov chain with the mentioned transition probability matrix $P$?

Comment: Could you define the period of a state in a Markov chain? Since there are transitions which are merely probable and not certain, it would seem there would really only be "probable periods" or something...

Comment: The period of state $i$ is the greatest common divisor (g.c.d.) of all integers $n\ge 1$ for which $P_{ii}^{(n)}\gt 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this very special case, note that starting at 0 it *must* go 0,1,2,3,4 and then from 4 it *might* go back to 0, making the least $n>0$ with $P_{00}^{(n)}>0$ to be $n=5.$ But again resuming from 4 it *might* go on to 5, then it must go to 6,7, then 0. That means that also $P_{00}^{(8)}>0.$ The gcd of 5 and 8 is 1, so if I'm following the definition right it seems here the period is 1.